# How to do two array operations parallelly in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, asynchronous

I have two arrays of objects having structures like this:

```
let groups = [
    {
        word: 'ok',
        id: 1,

    },
    {
        word: 'hi',
        id: 2,
    }
]


let words = [
    {
        name: 'hello',
        id: 1,
        meaning: 'Grreeting !',
        example: 'Hello how are you ?',
        groupId: 1
    },
    {
        name: 'morning',
        id: 3,
        meaning: 'First sign of the day !',
        example: 'Good Morning ?',
        groupId: 2

    }
]
```

A group has many words. I have an empty array `results[]` and I will store all matching words there. 
Now I want to search a keyword `hi` in both, groups and words array. The current approach I am following is :

- First, I will map through groups array, and if I keyword `hi` matched with any group name, 
  then I will push all the words having that groupId into my results array.
- Now I will map through the words array and if keyword `hi` matches with any word name then I will push that into results array.

Now, I want to do both these operations parallelly. Finding all the matches into words array and groups array parallelly and pushing data to results array.

Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: please add the wanted result as well.

Comment: It's important that you also describe _why_ you want it processed in parallel and _what you mean exactly by parallel_.  Are you running into actual performance problems? If you have an outrageous amount of data to process, it's possible that you need to do this operation in a web worker.  But that's highly unlikely, and you'd probably have other problems to resolve.  If you just want it to be asynchronous (since you've tagged it), you need to understand that it would _not be running multithreaded_, so it would _not be "real parallel"_.  Thus most likely defeating the purpose of it being async.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by first combining both arrays and then using the [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Filter) array prototype function.

```js
let groups = [
    {
        word: 'ok',
        id: 1,

    },
    {
        word: 'hi',
        id: 2,
    }
]


let words = [
    {
        name: 'hello',
        id: 1,
        meaning: 'Grreeting !',
        example: 'Hello how are you ?',
        groupId: 1
    },
    {
        name: 'morning',
        id: 3,
        meaning: 'First sign of the day !',
        example: 'Good Morning ?',
        groupId: 2

    }
];

let search = 'hi'; // get the search term from somewhere

let result = [ ...groups, ...words ] // combine arrays into one
    .filter(({ word, name }) => ( // 'extract' word/name properties
      word === search || name === search // return true when word or name matches searchterm
    ));
```

Little sidenote: in this solution searchterm can't be `undefined`, since that will always return true in the filter function.

Answer (score 0):

Although you could technically do this with a single loop, doing so would be at the cost of clarity and simplicity. Basically you'd do a loop with the index going from `0` to `Math.max(groups.length, words.length)` and then do your check on each array:

```
for (let n = 0, len = Math.max(groups.length, words.length); n < len; ++n) {
    if (n < groups.length) {
        // Check `groups[i]`
    }
    if (n < words.length) {
        // Check `words[i]`
    }
}
```

That way, you have a single loop, which is about as close to "in parallel" as you're going to get without using a web worker (which would almost certainly be overkill). But again, it doesn't buy you much, and costs you clarity and simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

Using async functions for the filter operations.
Not sure what you are doing that requires this, but note that they are *not running multithreaded*, and it's unlikely that this will be helpful or useful in solving the actual problem.  Also, the order these execute in will be deterministic for your example.

```js
const matches = async(list, key, match) => list.filter(x => x[key] === match);

let groups = [{
    word: 'ok',
    id: 1,

  },
  {
    word: 'hi',
    id: 2,
  }
]


let words = [{
    name: 'hello',
    id: 1,
    meaning: 'Grreeting !',
    example: 'Hello how are you ?',
    groupId: 1
  },
  {
    name: 'morning',
    id: 3,
    meaning: 'First sign of the day !',
    example: 'Good Morning ?',
    groupId: 2

  }
]

let matched = [];
Promise.all([
  matches(groups, 'word', 'hi').then(m => {
    matched = matched.concat(m);
    console.log('groups matched:', matched);
  }),
  matches(words, 'name', 'hello').then(m => {
    matched = matched.concat(m);
    console.log('words matched:', matched);
  })
]).then(res => {
  console.log("matched:", matched);
  console.log(".all results:", [...res[0], ...res[1]]);
})
console.log("matched immediate:", matched);
setTimeout(() => console.log("matched event loop delayed:", matched), 0);
```